# I can't update table's columns in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a tabe with values using this command :

```
 CREATE TABLE `news` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `title` text NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  `price` text NOT NULL,
  `link` text NOT NULL,
  `ppcode` text NOT NULL,
  `type` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
 )
```

And when i use this php codes i cant update any value of the columns :

```
 if (isset($_POST['edit'])){
 $delsql = "UPDATE news SET title='$newsubject',content='$newdisc',link='$newlink',
            price='$newprice',ppcode='$newppcode' WHERE id = '$id'";
 $result = mysql_query($delsql) or die(mysql_error());
 echo 'OK';
 }
```

Note : the version of MySQL is 3.5.2.2 and the version of PHP is 5.3

Comment: do you get the 'ok' msg

Comment: Firstly, do not use the `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated, use either `PDO` or the `mysqli_*` functions. Secondly, output the mysql error to find out what is wrong, see `mysqli_error`

Comment: Yes.Your query may not be executing due to the fact that `mysql_*` is deprecated instead replace it with `mysqli_*` and also return your `mysqli_error()`..!

Comment: one more thing your id column is int so no need pass in single quote pass without single quote

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai - It would fail with a function not found error, it is not the cause of this fault, just bad practice.

Comment: @DineshBhojvani - It may not need quoting in this instance, but it causes no harm and does not prevent it from functioning.

Comment: Ok msg appeared , but the problim is not in the php code because when i tried to create the table and set valuse manual ( From PhpMyAdmin ) i got ok and the values changed but the `id` is still a constant No. it still 0 in all news

Comment: You can see this image : `http://up.dev-point.com/uploads1/1aab9ffafdb61.png` this is what i mean in 'manual method'

Comment: When i run the code in `localhost apache server` i get ok in all statements of mysql_* or PDO and the columns data changed

Comment: FYI, to put links    `[text](http://url.com)`   [**test**](http://www.google.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use mysqli_* functions or PDO!!!!**

```
//db connection

global $conn;

$servername = "localhost";  //host name

$username = "username"; //username

$password = "password"; //password

$mysql_database = "dbname"; //database name

//mysqli prepared statement 

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());

mysqli_select_db($conn,$mysql_database) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");

$stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE news SET title=?,content=?,link=?,price=?,ppcode=? WHERE id =?");

            $stmt->bind_param('sssdii',$newsubject,$newdisc,$newlink,$newprice,$newppcode,$id);

 //   i corresponding variable has type integer
 //  d  corresponding variable has type double
//  s   corresponding variable has type string
//  b   corresponding variable is a blob and will be sent in packets

            $stmt->execute();

            $row_count= $stmt->affected_rows;
            $stmt->close();
             $conn->close();
```

Comment: what is `'sssdii'` in your example ?

Comment: and waht is the questions marks in `$conn->prepare` ?

Comment: 'sssdii'  data type of your parameter and ? it denote the parameters

Comment: OK, but what is  the problem here ? http://up.dev-point.com/uploads1/f949370d79c61.png

Comment: you dont need to change the ? this one  it automatically  taking parameters from this line $stmt->bind_param('sssdii',$newsubject,$newdisc,$newlink,$newprice,$newppcode,$id);  sequence should be same order

Comment: $result = $stmt->get_result();
        while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
        {
         
         $new_column[]=$row;
         
        }   @ßłẶckĤặwk

Comment: You mean i can get the data of a column like this : `$row['content'];` ? @jothi

Comment: but how can i insert a new data to the columns ?

Comment: you need insert query ah ?

Answer (score 0):

Beside all the suggestion on the comments

You have

```
 WHERE id = '$id'";
```

but `id` is `integer` not `text`

```
CREATE TABLE `news` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
```

Answer (score 0):

In image of phpmyadmin that you provided in comments you can see that A_I (auto_increment) is not active. Also primary key is not set. Set A_I to true for id and set it as primary key (under Index) in phpmyadmin. Then test it with your code.

Of course first insert new data which will have auto incremented id's.

Comment: When i save I get this msg `This is not a number!` then the phpmyadmin want me to add a value to 'title' column !!

Comment: i got that when i press ok ( to create the table with the columns )

Comment: You probably didn't set Lenght/Values column. Set it for INT 11 and VARCHAR 255 for example.